# Solutions of a linear diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $N(h)$ be the number of solutions of the following linear diophantine equation:
\begin{equation}
x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + \dots + (h-1)x_{h-1} = 6h-6;
\end{equation}
where $h\geq 2$ and solution means a vector $(z_1,\dots,z_{h-1})$ of non-negative integers satisfying the equation.

Does there exist a formula for $N(h)$ or at least an explicit expression for the behavior of $N(h)$ for $h\mapsto +\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Max Alekseyev observed, $N(h)$ is the number of partitions of $6h-6$ into at most $h-1$ parts. A complicated asymptotic formula exists for this quantity, as a special case of a result of Szekeres (1953). See [this paper by Canfield](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v4i2r6/pdf) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a simple but fairly good exponential upper bound for $N(h)$ when $h\gg 0$? I found the Hardy-Ramanujan asymptotic partition formula but if I got it right is for $q(n,k)$ when $n\gg k$. In the cases I am considering $n$ and $k$ are related.

Comment: @Mor Szekeres's asymptotic formula (summarized in the link in my post) applies for a wide range of pairs $(n,k)$. In particular, it applies for $(n,k)=(6h-6,h-1)$ as $h\to\infty$. On the other hand, the formula is complicated, so you will need some effort to get out of it what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I think I almost got it. One last question. What is the role of the $\epsilon > 0$ in Szekeres's theorem? If $\epsilon$ is small then then $e^{n^{1/2}g(u)+O(n^{-1/6+\epsilon})}$ goes as $e^{n^{1/2}g(u)}$ but for $\epsilon \gg 0$ it goes as $e^{n^{-1/6+\epsilon}}$. On the other hand is seems that the formula holds for any  $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @Mor In analysis, $\epsilon$ usually means an arbitrary (small) positive number. I suspect that in your case $n^{1/2} g(u)$ dominates over $n^{-1/2+\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, so that the exponent $(1+o(1))n^{1/2} g(u)$ is valid. Note also that $\gg$ does not always mean "much larger than". For example, in analytic number theory, it means that "larger than some constant times of".

Answer (score 1):

$N(h)$ can be expressed via [partition function $q$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionq.html) as $$N(h)=q(6h-6,h-1).$$