# System of two linear Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations, diophantine-geometry

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer. Denote by $f(n)$ the number of integral solutions of the following system
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = 3n; \\ 
\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)x_i = n(n+2); \\
x_1\geq x_2\geq \dots \geq x_n\geq 0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Is there any result on the asymptotic behavior of $f(n)$?

If we remove from the system se second equations we get the partitions of $3n$ in at most $n$ parts and the question basically boils down to
[Solutions of a linear diophantine equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441990/solutions-of-a-linear-diophantine-equation)
which has been fully answered.

Thank you.

Comment: The second equation can be replaced with $$\sum_{i=1}^n i x_i = \frac{n(n+2)+3n}2,$$ which makes it similar to the previous question. But in contrast to the previous question, here we also have inequalities between $x_i$.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, more like an extended comment.

It is possible to remove the inequalities by introducing new variables $y_i\ge 0$ according to
\begin{align}
x_n&=y_n\\
x_{n-1}-x_n&=y_{n-1}\\
\ldots\\
x_{1}-x_2&=y_{1}\\
\end{align}

This system is easily solved for $x$ in terms of $y$: $x_i=\sum\limits_{j=i}^ny_j$.

Now the original equations can be restated in terms of $y_i\ge 0$:
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^niy_i=3n
$$
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni(i+1)y_i=n^2+5n
$$
(For the second equation, the simplification given in the comment By Max Alekseev was used).
Thus $f(n)$ is given by the coefficient of $z^{3n}q^{n^2+5n}$ in the power series expansion of the function
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-z^kq^{k(k+1)}}.
$$
From this one sees that the problem is not a standard partition problem. But now one can use this generating function to calculate $f(n)$ and try to make some empirical observations about its behavior for large $n$.

Comment: Using this approach I found 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 16, 25, 42, 64, 107, 165, 256, 402, 594, 894, 1389, 1971, 2903, 4316, 6063, 8643, 12618, 17320, 24302, 34429, 46749, 64213... The sequence is not in OEIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you deduced that $f(n)$ is the coefficient of $z^{3n}q^{n^2+5n}$ is the power series expansion of that product?

Comment: @Mor 
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-z^kq^{k(k+1)}}=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{y_k=0}^\infty z^{ky_k}q^{k(k+1)y_k}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you. One last question. How did you compute so many terms of the sequence? I wrote a Maple script but it gets stuck at $n = 11$.

Comment: @Mor I used built in functions in Mathematica. It was able to calculate up to 30, but after that it takes too much time. I'm sure some experts can calculate to much higher values using some other more specialized CAS.